# use of class template requires template argument list, what do?

Tags: c++, templates

I have this template class that I am creating

```
template <class T> class ArrayLLN {
     private:
     ArrayLLN *next;
     T *item;
public:
     ArrayLLN(T i, ArrayLLN *n);
     ~ArrayLLN();
     void insert(T n, int i, int m);
     ArrayLLN *getnext();
     T *getitem();
     T remove(int i, int m);
};
```

The method that I am having issues with is the following.

```
ArrayLLN *getnext();
```

and is written out as

```
template <class T> ArrayLLN ArrayLLN <T> :: *getnext(){return next;}
```

As currently written I receive the error "error  C2955: 'ArrayLLN': use of class template requires template argument list"

The following configuration produced other errors

```
template <class T> ArrayLLN *ArrayLLN <T> :: getnext(){return next;)
```

What can be done to fix this error?

Could it be the declaration of these perhaps?

```
template <class T> T *ArrayLLN<T>  :: getitem(){return item;}
template <class T> ArrayLLN<T> *ArrayLLN<T>::getnext() { return next; }
template <class T> T ArrayLLN <T> :: remove (int i, int m){
    T *tmp == NULL;
    if(i == m && next){
        tmp = item;
        item = next ->getitem();
        next = next->getnext();
    }
    else if (i > m){
        m++;
        tmp = next -> remove(i,m);
    }
    return tmp; 
 }
```

Comment: "The following configuration produced other errors" - what other errors?

Comment: I don't receive the same error with your new code. `T *tmp == NULL` should be `T *tmp = NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is like this:

```
                        //  +-- argument list here                    +-- bracket
                        //  v                                         v not paren
template <class T> ArrayLLN<T> *ArrayLLN<T>::getnext() { return next; }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is still providing me the same error.

Comment: Odd. Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so I can reproduce the error?

Comment: I provided the rest of the method declarations and added in the other bits in my original post.  That's all the code I've got so far for this class.  I'm really new to templates so I'm fairly lost as to what to do.

Edit:  I guess I'm not particularly sure how to give less code for this as I feel I've got a pretty minimal amount of code to start with.

Comment: The only (compile-time) errors I can see are that `T *tmp == NULL;` has to be `T *tmp = NULL` and that `remove` has to return a pointer to work the way it is written. My compiler eats the rest without complaining.

Comment: So I've found that the error is actually coming from a different file all together.  I'm apparently really tired tonight.  This is apparently what is providing the error.

template <class T> class ArrayLL {

private:
 ArrayLLN *head;
 int size;}

I've come to determine that changing ArrayLLN *head; to ArrayLLN

Comment: I think I figured it out.  Changing `ArrayLLN *head;` to `ArrayLLN<T> head;` seems to have made the error go away.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the class, ArrayLLN is an *injected class name*, allowing you to omit the template argument list. Outside of the class, you must provide it. Secondly, the star is in the wrong place.

```
template <class T> ArrayLLN<T>* ArrayLLN <T> :: getnext(){return next;}
```